# Adding a Row to a DataTable question

Tags: c#

Greetings everyone-

In my code below I'm trying to add a Row from an existing DataTable (dtResult) into a new DataTable (dtCopyResult) if email address does not match.  So I guess my knowledge of ADO.NET is not up to par because whenever I try to run my below code, I get an "This Row already belongs to another table".  Please let me know how I can fix this..

Many Thanks

```
 if (checkBox1.Checked)  
                    {

                        for (int i = dtResult.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)  //dtResult is a DataTable
                        {
                            foreach (object email in emails)  //emails is an ArrayList of email addresses
                            {
                                if (email.ToString().ToUpper() != dtResult.Rows[i][3].ToString().ToUpper())
                                {
                                    dtCopyResult.Rows.Add(dtResult.Rows[i]);  //dtCopyResult is a new blank DataTable that I'm trying to add rows to
                                }
                            }

                        }

                    }
```

Comment: try using CopyResult.Rows.Add(new dtResult.Rows[i]);  Just a guess

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error message tells you, a DataRow belongs to a particular DataTable; you cannot just take it and add it to another one. What you can do is either

- create a *new* DataRow and fill it with the values from the old DataRow or
- use the [DataTable.ImportRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow.aspx) method:

  ```
  dtCopyResult.ImportRow(dtResult.Rows[i]);
  ```

Comment: +1 Wish i could have remembered the ImportRow :-) Definitely the way to go

Comment: Hi Heinzi-  On using ImportRow, will I get the entire row?  reason I ask is after my foreach loop above is complete I go back and search for a particular column so I can check what value is within that row and I'm getting "Column does not exist".  Thoughts?

Comment: @Josh: Your new DataTable must have the same columns as the old one. You can use DataTable.Clone for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ImportRow` function, full example here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308909

Answer (score 1):

One thing I noticed is that the new row will get added multiple times; once for each item in the emails collection.
You either need to keep a local list of items already added or loop through dtCopyResult to make sure you have not already added the email.

```
List<string> alreadyAdded = new List<string>();

if (email.ToString().ToUpper() != dtResult.Rows[i][0].ToString().ToUpper() 
    && !alreadyAdded.Contains(email.ToString()))
{
    dtCopyResult.ImportRow(_dt1.Rows[i]);
    alreadyAdded.Add(email.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it means the adding row is belong to "dtResult" and DataRow is an "Object" that represent data. Not data itselfs. so in this case u try to add DataRow object that belong to another table which will error.

another way to do is copy everything to dtCopy and delete it if condition mismatch.
Array is mainly to used to stored various type of object. In this case, if u gonna store only email u should use

```
List<string> emails = new List<string>();
emails.Add("test@example.com");
```

to enumerate rows for deleteing data

```
List<DataRow> removing = new List<DataRow>();
foreach(var row in table.AsEnumerable()) // or table.Rows
if(...condition)removing.Add(row);

foreach(var row in removing)table.Rows.Remove(row);
```

the reason to use 'removing' is if u loop through rows and removing it at the same time, means u change the enumerate which will cause error. becus .Net is not happy when u pull out something its looping.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
 dtCopyResult.Rows.Add(dtResult.Rows[i]);
```

with

```
DataRow rowToBeCopied = dtCopyResult.NewRow();
//Copy the row values..
rowToBeCopied.X = dtResult.Rows[i].X;
//Copy the remaining row values
dtCopyResult.Rows.Add(rowToBeCopied);
```